# Unable to transfer Picture on excel sheet to a jpeg file in 2010 excel with Window 7 OS

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to export the picture on excel spread sheet to an image file. I did some research and got the below codes which worked well when I used in Excel 2007 with Windows XP. when I am trying the same codes in 2010 excel with Windows 7 64bit the excel is getting crashed.

I am in need of this, please help me out.

```
Const saveSceenshotTo As String = "C:\Users\yourUserName\Desktop\" 
' change path to where you want to save
Const pictureFormat As String = ".jpg" ' change file extension

Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

Private Type uPicDesc
    Size As Long
    Type As Long
    hPic As Long
    hPal As Long
End Type

Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Private Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1


' run this sub to export pictures
Sub ExportPicturesToFiles()

    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    Dim pic As Shape
    For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        pic.Copy
        MyPrintScreen (saveSceenshotTo & Range("A" & i).Text & pictureFormat)
        i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub




Public Sub MyPrintScreen(FilePathName As String)

    Dim IID_IDispatch As GUID
    Dim uPicInfo As uPicDesc
    Dim IPic As IPicture
    Dim hPtr As Long

    OpenClipboard 0
    hPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP)
    CloseClipboard

    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A
        .Data4(0) = &H8B
        .Data4(1) = &HBB
        .Data4(2) = &H0
        .Data4(3) = &HAA
        .Data4(4) = &H0
        .Data4(5) = &H30
        .Data4(6) = &HC
        .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With

    With uPicInfo
        .Size = Len(uPicInfo)
        .Type = PICTYPE_BITMAP
        .hPic = hPtr
        .hPal = 0
    End With

    OleCreatePictureIndirect uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic
    SavePicture IPic, FilePathName
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using 64-bit Office?  http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp

Comment: Hi Tim, The Windows I am uisng is 64-bit. I am not sure about office. Thank you.

Comment: To be more specific the problem is in the following code "
    OleCreatePictureIndirect uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic
"

Comment: Click File - Help. In the About Microsoft Excel section does it say 32 bit or 64 bit? I'd guess 32 bit or you'd be getting compile errors.

Comment: Hi Rori, Yes you are right it is 32 bit. Thank you

Comment: Your code works for me as long as I don't try and step through it.

Comment: Hi Rory, Thanks for your help. 

This codes are working fine for me when I am running on Excel 2007 with Windows XP. But facing problem with same when I am running it in Excel 2010 32 Bit with Windows 7 bit 64.

The problem is at below line
OleCreatePictureIndirect uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic

I am new in this please help.

Imtiyaz

Comment: That's exactly what I'm testing on and it works with no problem.

Comment: Hi Rory, Thanks a lot for your time and effort :). I will check if some thing I can do. I will keep you posted.
Imtiyaz

Answer (score 0):

im using this code under excel 2013 on a win7 system, to save pictures from worksheet to .JPG:

The code is a bit old but works fine...

```
Option Explicit

Sub SavePic_to_JPG(Optional ByVal picname As String, Optional ByVal SheetName As String, Optional ByVal WB As Workbook, Optional ByVal SavePath As String) 'savepath avec "\" deja inclus
Dim Ch As ChartObject
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim PicBorder As Long
Dim Aff As Boolean

With Application
    Aff = .ScreenUpdating
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

If SavePath = "" Then SavePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ThisWorkbook

If SheetName = "" Then
    Set Sh = WB.ActiveSheet
Else
    Set Sh = WB.Sheets(SheetName)
End If

Dim Vis As Boolean
Dim Pic As Shape


Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
If picname <> "" Then
    Set Pic = Sh.Shapes(picname)
ElseIf TypeName(Selection) = "Picture" Then
    Set Pic = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
Else
    Set Pic = Sh.Shapes(1)
End If

If Err > 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo exiting
End If
On Error GoTo 0
With Pic
    .Copy
    Set Ch = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height) 

    With Ch
        .Name = "Chart_To_Add"
        .Border.LineStyle = 0 
        .Width = Pic.Width 
        .Height = Pic.Height 
        With .Chart 
            Ch.Activate
            ActiveChart.Paste
            On Error Resume Next
            Kill SavePath & Pic.Name & ".JPG"
            On Error GoTo 0
            .Export FileName:=SavePath & Pic.Name & ".JPG", FilterName:="JPG"
        End With
        .Delete 
    End With 'ch
End With

exiting:
Application.ScreenUpdating = Aff

Set Sh = Nothing
Set WB = Nothing
Set Pic = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to use chart to save an image because I think it will alter the resolution of image.